# What regex do i need to read this value '12,'

Tags: java, regex

```
if (thirdLastLine.matches("Tests run: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]),  Failures: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])")) {
            System.out.println("first choice");
            String[] splitedString = thirdLastLine.split("\\s");
            //  System.out.println("splitedString: " + splitedString);
            System.out.println("splitedString: " + Arrays.toString(splitedString));

        int lastIndexofArray = (splitedString.length) - 1;
        System.out.println("lastIndexOfArray: " + lastIndexofArray);

        //for the test run:
        int thirdIndexofArray = (splitedString.length) - 4;
        System.out.println("thirdIndexofArray: " + thirdIndexofArray);

        int returnedInteger = Integer.parseInt(splitedString[lastIndexofArray]);

       int returnedThirdInteger = Integer.parseInt(splitedString[thirdIndexofArray]);
        System.out.println("You failed: " + returnedInteger + " " + "test");
          System.out.println("Numbers of test:  " + returnedThirdInteger + "test");
        feedbackString = "You failed: " + returnedInteger + " " + "test";

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing found");

    }
```

`thirdLastLine` contains string:

> Tests run: 12,  Failures: 4

in a txt file. The failure bit works fine but cant seem to get the Test run bit to work because of the character. I cant read the value next to the 'Test run: ' because it has a comma next to it and my regex doesn't satisfy the requirements. any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: Why not `\d+` and then compare the value to 12?..

Comment: you can use http://regexr.com/ to check your regex pattern

Comment: There is no `,` in your regular expression.

Comment: @MarounMaroun i am new to regex and wouldnt know how to apply that. can you please explain more?

Comment: @icke yeah I know but have tried all I can add it as it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, I suggest you use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to get a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and then use [`Formatter` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Tests run: (\\d+), Failures: (\\d+)");
String thirdLastLine = "Tests run: 12, Failures: 4";
Matcher m = p.matcher(thirdLastLine);
if (m.matches()) {
    int testCount = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int failureCount = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));

    System.out.printf("Numbers of tests: %d tests%n", testCount);
    String feedbackString = String.format("You failed: %d tests",
            failureCount);
    System.out.println(feedbackString);
} else {
    System.out.println("Nothing found");
}
```

Output is

```
Numbers of tests: 12 tests
You failed: 4 tests
```

Comment: I have just tried your code but it returns the else statement and I don't know why that is

Comment: Then your `thirdLastLine` doesn't contain the `String` you said it does. Note that I included the `String` I tested with in my code, and the output.

Comment: The number ranges held by the String thirdLastLine changes in the txt file depending on the submission made. and I have tried your code with a txt file that contains exactly the same string as you declared but still returns the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma after the first digits:

```
"Tests run: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]),  Failures: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])"    
#                         here __^
```

And may there are unknown number of spaces (or tab) before "Failure", so:

```
"Tests run:\s+([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]),\s+Failures:\s+([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])"
```

Comment: yeah I know but when I take it out, it doesn't match to the string as it has a comma by default. This is what thirdLastLine looks like 'Tests run: 12, Failures: 4'

Comment: @Buzz Your regular expression is missing the comma.

Comment: @Buzz: That's what I say, add a comma in your regex.

Comment: I am really new to regex. how do I add this to my regex please?

Comment: @Buzz: Just copy the regex I gave in place of yours.

Comment: I am sorry didn't notice it as I mistakenly deleted it when I edited the code. I have now added it but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match the digit expression 
`2[0-3]|1\d|\d`

This will match from 0 to 23

If you put that in all your matching pattern and taking into account the answer of JE SUIS CHARLIE,

it becomes 
`"Tests run: (2[0-3]|1\d|\d),  Failures: (2[0-3]|1\d|\d)"`

Comment: my regex matches from 1-23 I think. I am just confused on how to return the value as there is a comma attached

Answer (score 0):

You need a Pattern and matcher to get the groups out.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Then you can check it matches and extract the matching groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Tests run: ([0-9]+), Failures: ([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(thirdLastLine);
if(m.matches()) {
   String testsRun = m.group(1);
   String failedTests = m.group(2);
   System.out.println("You failed: " + failedTests + " " + "tests");
   System.out.println("Numbers of tests:  " + testsRun + "tests");
} else {
    System.out.println("Nothing found");
}
```

Of course you will probably want to turn the results into integers.

Comment: I have tried this and it returns the else statement after converting to integers.

Comment: I have just used my regex from above in your code and it works. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Tests run: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]),  Failures: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(thirdLastLine);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String testsRun = m.group(1);
        String failedTests = m.group(2);

        int testsRunsOutput = Integer.parseInt(testsRun);
        int failedTestsOutput = Integer.parseInt(failedTests);

        System.out.println("You failed: " + failedTestsOutput + " " + "tests");
        System.out.println("Numbers of tests:  " + testsRunsOutput + "tests");
        System.out.println("Numbers of tests: " + testsRunsOutput + " " + "You failed: " + failedTestsOutput + " " + "tests");
        feedbackString = "Numbers of tests: " + testsRunsOutput + " " + "You failed: " + failedTestsOutput + " " + "tests";

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing found");
    }
```

I have just used same regex as my question and the code from @Wil Selwood.
When I run a thirdLastLine with 'Tests run: 12,  Failures: 4'

Output:
Numbers of tests: 12 You failed: 4 tests